# Android Studio - Images not showing in emulator (in the emulator Toast shows path, also number of photos come,no images. )

Tags: java, android, xml, image

`I cant solve the problem, many times i checked codes but i cant find issue,everything comes from storage, but not showing images. please help me. Thank you`

`grid_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        android:id="@+id/imageee"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#333333">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/gallery_number"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity`

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    RecyclerView recyclerViewG;
    GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;
    List<String> imageList;
    TextView gallery_number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gallery_number = findViewById(R.id.gallery_number);
        recyclerViewG = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        } else {
            loadImages();
        }
    }

    public void loadImages(){
        recyclerViewG.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewG.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
        imageList = ImagesGallery.listOfImages(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: list" + imageList);
        galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, imageList, new GalleryAdapter.PhotoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPhotoClick(String path) {
                //do something with photo
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerViewG.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);

        gallery_number.setText("Photos ("+imageList.size()+")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if ( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loadImages();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`GalleryAdapter`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> images;
    protected PhotoListener photoListener;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> images, PhotoListener photoListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.photoListener = photoListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final String image = images.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.imagex);
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: img" + image);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                photoListener.onPhotoClick(image);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imagex;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imagex = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }

    public interface PhotoListener{
        void onPhotoClick(String path);
    }
}
```

`ImagesGallery`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class ImagesGallery {

    public static ArrayList<String> listOfImages (Context context){
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImaages = new ArrayList<>();
        String ablosutePathOfImages;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection ={MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy+" DESC");
        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            ablosutePathOfImages = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            listOfAllImaages.add(ablosutePathOfImages);
            Log.d(TAG, "listOfImages : uri " + listOfAllImaages);
        }


        return listOfAllImaages;
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mm.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

}
```

`Thank you`

Comment: when i run my  phone on the android studio, all images seeing. but emulator not showing images, problem is emulator.

Comment: ı think, permission is not enough for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28  Because, when ı run lower sdk emulators they show pictures

Comment: anyone know how to make permission for list above  ( imageList = ImagesGallery.listOfImages(this); )

Comment: Solution is "android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" " ı couldn't write this code in manifest.